# Runtime Error Using Char Array to Display a String in VC2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am "running" this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    char name[5] = {'J', 'a', 'k', 'e', '\0'};

    std::cout << name[5];

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

referring to my C++ Primer, this code is correct. The Run-Time error I am receiving is this (copy and pasted directly from the dialog):

*"Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'name' is being used without being initialized."*

I do understand this error, but I don't see how I can fix it. I did *Initialize* the variable. I want to know how I can solve this, or if I did make a mistake, how I could fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Name` is 5 element array, therefore, the last element is `name[4]`.

You're trying to print the "sixth" element, which doesn't exist with:  `std::cout << name[5];`

If you'd like to print the entire thing, then `std::cout<<name;` would work well as you correctly null terminated your array.

If you want to print the fifth element ('\0'), then `std::cout<<name[4]`.

Comment: How could I have missed that? That's embarrassing. But even once I change it, It won't display the series of characters as a string. Is it supposed to?

Comment: @Jake2k13 Just use std::cout<<name; char[] will decay to char* which will call std::cout.operator<<(char*) which prints a "c string" kind of thing - the entire name.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. So, printing the variable I would just output 'name'. To point to a single element within the array, I would use name[] (with a value within the range)?

Comment: @Jake2k13 pretty much, although I'd just advise using std::string name = "Jake"; std::cout<<name; (you need #include <string> for this)

Comment: Ok, I can see why that would be more efficient. Thank you again.

Comment: @Jake2k13 It won't be more "efficient", it will be nicer though, as you can omit the trailing \0 and write the value in a nice fashion. char*s are C strings, std::strings are C++ strings.

Comment: So in terms of code optimization, using an array to display characters is faster than using strings (regardless of the tedious work)?

Comment: @Jake2k13 It is very unlikely. You can look at the assembly your compiler generates. The overhead for this is absolutely neglectable. This is really something you shouldn't concern yourself with as a beginner. In more technical terms, the std::string object has a small handle that contains the length of the string its holding and potentially some other small stuffs - this means that sizeof(std::string("xyz")) can be slightly larger than sizeof("xyz") ("xyz" here being const char* in C++)", but it REALLY doesn't matter, again, you don't need to care about this.